# An Inequality with $e^{-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I couldnt be able to show the following:

There are no positive constants M,R and $\alpha$ such that for $|z| \geq R $, $ |\frac{e^{-z}}{z}|\leq \frac {M}{|z|^{\alpha}}$.

In fact it seems that the statement is not true but I should have mistakes in my computations. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $z=-N$ for any sufficiently large real number $N$. Then the left side grows exponentially large and the right side stays bounded.